# why this code is not jumping to chat.jsp which is verification file?

Tags: jsp, authentication

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>   
<%@page import="java.io.PrintWriter"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Verification</title>
   </head>
    <body>

    <%
     String driver ="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
     String database = "login";


     response.setContentType("text/html");
     try {
    Class.forName(driver);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
        }
     Connection con = null;
     Statement statement = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;

    String uname = request.getParameter("username").toString();
    String pass = request.getParameter("password").toString();

      try {
    Class.forName(driver);
            Connection conn = 
     DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abc? 
     zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull [root on Default schema]", "root", 
      "");
             statement = conn.createStatement();
            String query = "select *from chatting where username ='" + uname 
            +"' and password='" + pass+ "';";
                resultSet  = statement.executeQuery(query);

                    if( resultSet.next())
                    {      
                           request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("uname", uname);
            session.setAttribute("pass1", pass);
                       response.sendRedirect("chat.jsp");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        response.sendRedirect("error.jsp");
                    }
      }

        catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error in connection");
        e.printStackTrace();
       }

       %>
    </body>
   </html>
```

i am new to jsp so this can be wrong but where is it going wrong no errors are seen on chrome browser console but the submit button does not make it jump to other page i have not used java bean or java class
please help me out i dont want to use java bean also
is thr a way to join these both jsp files if yes,please include the steps

Comment: does it forward to error.jsp page if it is true then check your getConnection,resultSet and change chat.jsp to /chat.jsp

Comment: no it isnt jumping to error.jsp also

Comment: try to change from chat.jsp to /chat.jsp and most importantly add return; after response.sendRedirect("chat.jsp");